Let $ S=\{-1,0,\frac{1}{2},\sqrt{2},2 \}$. Solve for $(1)\ \dfrac{1}{x} \leq \dfrac{1}{2} \ \ \ \ (2)\ 10 \geq\dfrac{5}{2x}$.

Let $ S=\{-1,0,\frac{1}{2},\sqrt{2},2 \}$. Use substitution to determine which elements of $S$ satisfy the given equality. $(1)\ \dfrac{1}{x} \leq \dfrac{1}{2} \ \ \ \ (2)\ 10 \geq\dfrac{5}{2x}$

$(1): \dfrac{1}{x} \leq \dfrac{1}{2} \Rightarrow  2 \leq x$
$(2):10 \geq\dfrac{5}{2x} \Rightarrow 20x \geq 5 \Rightarrow x \geq \dfrac{1}{4}$
But $-1$ can be plugged into the original equalities and work for both expressions, so I don't understand where I went wrong.

Your two implications are valid only if $x>0$ (and (1),(2) hold for every $x<0$, and make no sense if $x=0$) + I disagree with the downvote.

You can't multiply both sides by a variable if you're not sure of its sign. The inequality reverses if you multiply by a negative quantity.

It is better to consider for example $\frac1{x}-\frac12 =\frac{2-x}{2x}\le0$ for the first part and similarly for the next.

It is much simpler to consider separately the cases $x<0,x=0,x>0$, like in my first comment.

OP: for a general method to solve polynomial inequalities you may check out the method of intervals.

Consider the first problem:
Commence with a categorical discussion as dividing by a negative number results in a sign change: i. For x = 0, the inequality does not hold true. ii. For x less than 0, a change of sign yields 2 ≥ x, resulting in x = 2. iii. For x greater than 0, 2 ≤ x, leading to x = 1/2, √2.

Graphing the equation is an alternative method. The problem can be solved by graphing f(x) = 1/x and y = 1/2. A visual representation is provided for reference.https://i.sstatic.net/fzqR8Yf6.png

In more complex equations, terms can be reorganized to form new fractional equations. When the value is greater than 0, the numerator and denominator should be the same, and the denominator should not equal 0. The reverse is also true.

Firstly, $x=0$ is definitely impossible as you cannot divide by $0$. As there are negative and positive elements in the set $S$, we can have two cases.
Case $\boldsymbol1$: $\ \ $If $x>0$.
If $x>0$, for the first inequality, we can multiply by $2x$ on both sides and obtain $x\geq 2$, which you have also gotten. For the second inequality, you've also done it correctly if $x$ is positive, obtaining $x
\geq\frac14$. Combining the two results, we get $x\geq 2$, so the element of $\boldsymbol2$ in $S$ satisfies the inequalities. Note that we also are in the case of $x>0$ so we need to consider this as well, but since $x\geq 2$, we can ignore that.
Case $\boldsymbol2$: $\ \ $If $x<0$.
If $x<0$, when we attempt to solve for the inequalities, if we multiply on both sides by a multiple of $x$, where the coefficient is positive, that multiple would be negative, and multiplying on both sides of an inequality by a negative number requires you to "flip" the sign. This means changing $>$ to $<$, $<$ to $>$, $\geq$ to $\leq$ or $\leq$ to $\geq$. For the first inequality, we can get $x\leq 2$, and for the second, $x\leq \frac14$. Since $x<0$ as well, all real numbers $x$ with $x<0$ satisfy both inequalities, and so the element of $\boldsymbol{-1}$ also works.
If you're confused about why the sign needs to be "flipped", consider the following simple example: $-x<1$. If you simply multiply both sides by $-1$ without changing the sign (after already considering that $x\neq 0$), you get $x<-1$, which is incorrect as say we have $x=-2$, then we would have $2<1$, a contradiction.
So if you multiply or divide by a negative number on both sides in an inequality in the future, please don't forget to flip the inequality sign. If the variable you're solving for is not specified to be positive or negative, you should consider cases for each (and of course, $0$).
